emitting particles from the ends of hair curves
I'm trying to create a "poof" of particles on impact from the end of a cosmetic brush.
I've faked it but I want to be able to use weight mapping on the curves to generate the particles, then release them when the brush hits another object in the scene.
2nd question: I can not seem to paint the root of the curves. any reason for that?
Thanks!
photo for example (not a render) (that might be obvious)


Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] link below your post, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

As a very simple approach you can try adding another object (e.g. a plane or something simple like that), make it a child of the object you want that particles to be emitted from, adjust "emitter plane" location and you'll get your particles emitted from wherever you want.
Obviously emitter object would need to be hidden in this case.
